# wubi bcdeditor real-mode boot sector default boot

Tags: windows-7, xubuntu, wubi, bcdedit

I have installed Xubuntu using wubi on windows 7 starter. 
I use Xubuntu often, hence setting default boot to Xubuntu makes sense :-)

This is current listing: 
PS C:\Windows\system32> `.\bcdedit.exe /v`

```
Windows Boot Manager 
--------------------
identifier              {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
device                  partition=E:
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {7ea2e1ac-2e61-4728-aaa3-yyyyyyyyyyyy}
default                 {ddf9919a-60c6-11e5-8ca7-zzzzzzzzzzzz}
resumeobject            {ddf99199-60c6-11e5-8ca7-aaaaaaaaaaaa}
displayorder            {ddf9919a-60c6-11e5-8ca7-bbbbbbbbbbbb}
                        {ddf99198-60c6-11e5-8ca7-cccccccccccc}
toolsdisplayorder       {b2721d73-1db4-4c62-bf78-dddddddddddd}
timeout                 360

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {ddf9919a-60c6-11e5-8ca7-eeeeeeeeeeee}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 7
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-ffffffffffff}
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {ddf99199-60c6-11e5-8ca7-gggggggggggg}
nx                      OptIn
detecthal               Yes

Real-mode Boot Sector
---------------------
identifier              {ddf99198-60c6-11e5-8ca7-hhhhhhhhhhhh}
device                  partition=H:
path                    \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
description             Xubuntu
```

I tried this: 
PS C:\Windows\system32> `.\bcdedit.exe /default {ddf99198-60c6-11e5-8ca7-hhhhhhhhhhhh}`

Output:

```
The default entry is not valid as specified.
Run "bcdedit /?" for command line assistance.
The parameter is incorrect.
```

I tried this also: 
PS C:\Windows\system32> `bcdedit /bootsequence {ddf99198-60c6-11e5-8ca7-hhhhhhhhhhhh} /addfirst` 
Output:

```
The entry list data is not valid as specified.
Run "bcdedit /?" for command line assistance.
The operation completed successfully.
```

Next, I trial with this: 
PS C:\Windows\system32> `.\bcdedit.exe /displayorder {ddf99199-60c6-11e5-8ca7-hhhhhhhhhhhh} /addfirst`

Output:

```
 The entry list data is not valid as specified.
 Run "bcdedit /?" for command line assistance.
 The operation completed successfully.
```

Non of them worked, any other directions ? :-) ?

Answer (score 0):

None of those GUID's seem to be valid. For one thing, all the characters must be
hexadecimal digits. For another, it does not seem likely that all the last 12 digits
are the same, as shown, even if they are valid hexadecimal digits.